# Using Replace in Mysql with Regex

Tags: mysql, regex, replace

I discovered a # of records in my table where a field seems to have carriage returns. I found them using:

```
Select Field from Table WHERE Field REGEXP "\r\n"
```

I'd like to remove them but using regex in replace did not work:

```
Update Table set Field=Replace(Field,REGEXP "\r\n",'') where Field REGEXP "\r\n"
```

As an aside I have found several fields that did NOT match the regex query but still show up in the memo field as broken e..g

```
Queen

Anne
```

vs

```
Queen Ann
```

Is there any other Regex character I should be adding so I can search on any/all combinations and replace where I am not getting simply a space?

Comment: MySQL does not natively support regex replacement. It is possible using a user-defined function, in the other answers I linked.  [Also here...](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/986826/how-to-do-a-regular-expression-replace-in-mysql/6216513#6216513)

Comment: MariaDB has REGEXP_REPLACE.

Comment: Why did you think you needed a regexp? You're replacing a fixed string, not a pattern.

Answer (score 1):

You just want `replace()`:

```
Update Table
    set Field = Replace(Field, '\r\n', '')
    where Field REGEXP '\r\n';
```

MySQL should recognize `'\r'` and `'\n'` in any string (see [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/string-literals.html)).